# Reflection of polar functions

Tags: functions, polar-coordinates, transformation, reflection

For whatever reason, I am having a complete brain block; I would like to reflect the arithmetic spiral
$$
r=\frac{\theta}{2\pi}
$$
about the polar axis. This should be possible? But I can't quite figure out how to go about it. The spiral crosses the polar axis at every integer value of $r$, so it seems to me that as $r$ increases after passing through $\theta=0$ at an integer, the angle needs to decrease from $2\pi$, rather than continue increasing as in the original function. I have a hard time finding examples online. I am looking for something like this:

[image: this].

Comment: Take $r=(10 \pi-\theta)/(2 \pi)$ for example.

Comment: Works, but is limited to $10\pi$, the key was seeing $-\theta$ in your example! It turns out I had foolishly not been considering negative angles and a negative range for $\theta$, so this actually just comes about for $r=\frac{-\theta}{2\pi}\quad(-\infty < \theta \leq 0)$.